# Cannot start MonoGame from SSH, but can from GUI

Tags: linux, ssh, mono, raspberry-pi, monogame

So i would like to start a game from my SSH terminal.

Its really wierd, when i do it directly from my linux GUI, it works. But when im connected from distance using a SSH client, it just crash. Seems like it has something to do with my display drivers.

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for OpenTK.DisplayDevice ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory '/dev/dri' not found.
  at System.IO.Directory.ValidateDirectoryListing (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean& stop) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenTK.Platform.Linux.LinuxFactory.CreateDisplay (System.IntPtr& gbm_device, System.IntPtr& egl_display) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenTK.Platform.Linux.LinuxFactory.get_gpu_fd () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenTK.Platform.Linux.LinuxFactory.CreateDisplayDeviceDriver () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenTK.DisplayDevice..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at OpenTK.NativeWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow.Initialize (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TestGame.Game1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TestGame.Program.RunGame () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TestGame.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for OpenTK.DisplayDevice ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory '/dev/dri' not found.
  at System.IO.Directory.ValidateDirectoryListing (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, System.Boolean& stop) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFileSystemEntries (System.String path, System.String searchPattern, FileAttributes mask, FileAttributes attrs) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path, System.String searchPattern) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenTK.Platform.Linux.LinuxFactory.CreateDisplay (System.IntPtr& gbm_device, System.IntPtr& egl_display) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenTK.Platform.Linux.LinuxFactory.get_gpu_fd () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenTK.Platform.Linux.LinuxFactory.CreateDisplayDeviceDriver () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at OpenTK.DisplayDevice..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at OpenTK.NativeWindow..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow.Initialize (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGameWindow..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.OpenTKGamePlatform..ctor (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamePlatform.Create (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game game) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TestGame.Game1..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TestGame.Program.RunGame () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at TestGame.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I though creating a bash script that would then call itself the method to start the game would do the job, but unfortunately it does the same result.

Basically, when i run the SAME EXACT command in my linux GUI, the game starts with no problem, but when i run the SAME EXACT command from distance in my SSH, the game does not fire up and it just stuck there.

```
mono /home/pi/.../game/TestGame.exe
```

I am running a Linux Raspbian, on a raspberry PI.
My raspberry PI is connected on my screen. When plugged with my keyboard it lauches, when trying from my other computer using ssh, it crash giving the error we see up here.

I would appreciate any help.

thanks alot !
Kevin

Comment: Did you enable X forwarding when you made the ssh connection?

Comment: I looked at my sshd_config file and x11 forwarding is enabled. I also connected to my raspberry pi using the -x argument and it dind't help, same problem happening :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on my discoveries,

There is 2 things to look at if you ever get this mistake :

1. Check if you have X11 forwarding activated in your SSH terminal.
2. Type this magical line to tell the SSH which monitor to use.. Else any graphical software will crash at startup..

   export DISPLAY=:0

Thanks,
Kev

Comment: You should clarify that these are either/or.  #1 will make the game appear on the computer where you are sitting and controlling ssh.  #2 will make the game appear on the Pi's own HDMI output.